# Como fazer uma pesquisa no Google com C#?

Tags: c#, api, google

Eu preciso buscar um termo qualquer no Google e obter uma lista com os resultados dessa busca. Estou tentando fazer isso utilizando a [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) mas não estou tendo resultados satisfatórios.

Por exemplo, quando eu busco o termo **"licitações"** com o meu código eu recebo 1.510.000 de resultados. Quando eu faço a busca do mesmo termo direto no navegador eu obtenho 11.800.000 resultados.

Como eu faço para obter os todos 11.800.000 dessa pesquisa?

Segue abaixo o meu código em C#:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string apiKey = "AIzaSyCVGlnfsGaaJ3HYTHVu6OH_jBaIFJQYrH0";
        string cx = "013638634553566051485:xwnfxqp2pso";
        string query = "licitações";
        var svc = new Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1.CustomsearchService(
        new BaseClientService.Initializer { ApiKey = apiKey });
        var listRequest = svc.Cse.List(query);
        listRequest.Cx = cx;
        var search = listRequest.Execute(); //listRequest.Fetch(); This method has been removed
        foreach (var result in search.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", result.Title);
            Console.WriteLine("Link: {0}\n", result.Link);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Infelizmente, ou felizmente, os números são diferentes por algumas razões.

### Custom Search vs Google.com

Em geral, um motor de busca personalizado procura através de um conjunto de sites que você especificar. No entanto, você pode configurar o seu motor de busca personalizado para pesquisar toda a web . Neste caso, no entanto, os resultados não são susceptíveis de corresponder aos retornados pelo Google Web Search, por várias razões:

- Apesar de um motor de busca personalizado está configurado para pesquisar toda a Web, ele é projetado para destacar os resultados de seus sites.
- O seu motor de busca personalizado não inclui funções do Google Web Search , como OneBox, resultados de pesquisa em tempo real, busca universal, funções sociais ou resultados personalizados.
- Se o seu motor de busca personalizado inclui mais de dez locais, os resultados podem vir de um subconjunto de nosso índice e diferem dos resultados de um operador de pesquisa "site:" feitas no Google.com.

Se você quiser obter resultados mais completos em seu motor de busca personalizado, tente uma das seguintes opções:

- Seção Preferências de pesquisa guia Basics Painel de Controle, selecione Pesquisar somente os sites incluídos . Seja certo não para incluir mais de dez locais no separador sites. Os domínios que lhe adicionar serão incluídos na contagem total, mas não as páginas dos domínios é tomado em consideração.
- Seção Preferências de pesquisa guia Basics Painel de Controle, selecione Pesquisar na web, mas enfatizam locais incluídos .
- Adicionar restrito ao seu motor de busca que cumprir um destes requisitos missões.

---

Temos uma pergunta similar em [nosso "irmão mais velho](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20182667/4843158), caso queira verificar.

> **Nota:** O texto foi traduzido utilizando o Google Translate, então pode conter alguns erros de tradução. O texto original podese ser encontrado [neste link](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en).